# Use VS2010 internal browser for testing

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'd like VS2010 to open an internal browser window to test my web application instead of always opening a new "default browser" window. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably want to test your app in an external browser unless one of the browsers that your users will be using is the internal browser of visual studio.

Comment: Hum I guess it's using IE as the browser, am I wrong?

Comment: It's probably using the IE layout engine, Mosaic, but that is somewhat different from internet explorer. Every browser has its own differences, even between browsers which use the same engine. See Camino versus Firefox for an example.

Comment: I created an ASPX file, clicked on Browser with... Selected Internal Web Browser and clicked on "Set as Default". Nice. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an ASPX file, clicked on Browser with... Selected Internal Web Browser and clicked on "Set as Default".